# Rails to Labview networked connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, redis, database-connection, labview

I have a Rails server that needs to send a little bit of a data to a LabVIEW system when a record is saved. That shouldn't be too hard in Rails using an after_save hook and quite possibly a redis worker.

I have three really short and primitive fields that need to be dispatched for each event.  We have thought of two solutions:

1. The facility has solid internal networking and some network shares. I could write a ruby script to append to a file with comma separated values. LabVIEW could tail the file (I assume) and read the events on change. Each one will have a unique ID so LabVIEW could "catch up" if it misses a whole bunch of them (the system goes down).
2. Use a socket to send a custom object or even just a YAML string (or whatever) to LabVIEW. This approach seems harder to implement with disconnection handling and things, but I like that Rails can tell if anyone's listening. Could a redis worker be told to keep a port open and then process the job queue by writing to the socket? Probably..

I'm a fairly novice programmer just starting out, so any tips you can give on making this type of connection would be great.

Comment: thanks for formatting jakub

Answer (score 0):

I'm now thinking that the proper way to do this is certainly with XML.  This would be super easy using a controller action that formats xml. like this:https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1212245  I could also write the XML to a file, I believe, though I prefer the former.